# How do I make 2 threads work simultaneously on adding something to a list and removing something from the list in an infinite loop in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Im working on some Code which is supposed to be having 2 Threads. One of those Threads adds random Books from a filled list1 to a different book list2 and the other removes Books from the same list2 both in an infinite loop.
The second Thread waits a little before starting, so the first Thread has enough time to fill up the List2 with some Books to remove.

Heres what I came up with right now:

```
public class BookFabric implements Runnable {

private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

private List<Book> filledBookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

public BookFabric() {
}

public BookFabric(List<Book> list) {

    this.filledBookList = list;
}

private void addBook(Book b) {
    bookList.add(b);
}

public void addRandomBook() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    addBook(filledBookList.get(rand.nextInt(filledBookList.size())));
    System.out.println("Book added");

}

public void deleteRandomBook() {
    int r = 0;
    if (!bookList.isEmpty()) {
        while (r > bookList.size()) {
            r = (int) ((Math.random() * 50));
        }
        Book b = null;
        b = bookList.remove(r);
        if (b.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("Random Book removed");
        }
    }
}

public void showBooks() {
    for (Book temp : bookList) {
        System.out.println(temp.getBookName());

    }

}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            this.addRandomBook();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
 }
}


   public class Book {

    String bookName;
    
    public Book(String name) {
        this.bookName = name;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }
    
    
}




public class Thread1 extends BookFabric implements Runnable {


BookFabric b; 

public Thread1(BookFabric bF) {
    this.b = bF;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    
    while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
                b.deleteRandomBook();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

}

```
 public class Main {


      public static void main(String[] args) {

       List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
       
       Book b1 = new Book("first book");
       Book b2 = new Book("second book ");
       Book b3 = new Book("third book");
       
       bookList.add(b1);
       bookList.add(b2);
       bookList.add(b3);
       
       BookFabric b = new BookFabric(bookList);
       
       Thread1 t = new Thread1(b);
       
       Thread t1 = new Thread(b);
       Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
       
       t1.start();
       t2.start();
   }

}
```

t1 in the Main Method works as intended. It Creates Random Books in an infinite loop. But for some reason t2 doesent even start at all and doesent end up removing any of those created random books from the list. Im pretty much out of ideas in this one. Would be very thankful for any kind of ideas on what I can do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Memory Model (JMM) is the relevant documentation here.

> t1 in the Main Method works as intended

No, it doesn't. This is the first problem of the JMM: The JMM decrees areas where JVMs are free to do whatever they want. That means that the output of the JVM is **non deterministic** in effect: A JVM is free to always do A, or always do B, or flip a coin, or look at the phase of the moon, and more - and they still adhere to the spec. That's not just academic: The popular JVM impls out there all actually do this, because they can run far more efficiently that way.

It means that effectively you can't test your code to detect that you messed up (by relying on the JVM's choice - which is bad), and if it seems to work right now, there's no guarantee it works tomorrow.

Basically, the JMM allows the JVM to flip an evil coin sometimes: Evil in the sense that it will flip the same way every time during your dev and test cycle and then flips the other way just as you're giving that important demo.

The only way to play the game, is **to ensure the evil coin is never flipped in the first place**.

To do that, you need to remember the following rule:

**All fields that are shared between threads must never be accessed unless HB/HA relationships are set up first, *OR* it is a read-only concept for the entirety of the concurrent process**.

In other words, here you have a field (`bookList`, or to be more specific, the backing array within the arraylist that bookList is pointing at) that is modified by one thread whilst another is running that also wants to read it, and  and thus, evil coinflips occur and this code is broken, whether your tests say so or not. You will 'randomly' observe some or all of the changes or not, or at least the JVM is free to let thread B see what thread A did or not in a haphazard fashion and you can't rely on any of it.

HB/HA stands for 'happens-before/happens-after'. The JMM describes certain situations for which the JVM guarantees that it is not possible to observe the *lack* of change caused by the Happens-Before line in the Happens-After line.

Without HB/HA, you get no such guarantee. To make that clear with an example:

```
class State {
    static int a = 0, b = 0;
}

class T1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(randomAmount);
        State.a = 10;
        State.b = 20;
    }
}

class T2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(randomAmount);
        int myB = State.b;
        int myA = State.a;
        System.out.println(myA + " " + myB);
    }
}
```

If you run this code, fire up the two threads, then any of these outputs are all 'legal' - it is not a buggy JVM. Your code is the buggy code, and note that it is also legal for a JVM to never ever produce one or more of these answers. That should really sail home the point of that evil coin analogy - you just can't write software that doesn't solve HB/HA first, because it's a random clusterbomb otherwise:

- `0 0`
- `10 20`
- `10 0`
- `0 20`

Note in particular that last one. That sure **seems** impossible. thread1 always writes a before it writes b, and thread 2 reads b before a, so can it possibly be that b does read 20, but somehow a is still 0? **And yet, that is legal**, and the reason is that the JVM likes to run quickly, and some JVM implementations (most, actually), will run code in parallel. The JVM merely guarantees that you can't observe things running in parallel unless you use timing to do so (and makes no guarantees on timing at all). If you wouldn't be able to observe it, it will run things in parallel for speed reasons.

Thus, the JVM is free to run a=10 and b=20 in parallel.

So, how do you establish HB/HA? That's quite a complicated topic; it involves the primitives `synchronized` and `volatile`, or using Java API that is thread-related, such as `AtomicLong`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `someThread.start()`, etcetera. The docs will say (and the reason they establish HB/HA is generally because their implementations use synchronized/volatile under the hood).

You're doing none of that, thus, no HB/HA relationships, thus this code is plain broken and not in a way that a test can ever reliably catch.

In practice, though, trying to hand-manage this stuff is hard and error prone. Obviously it is: Just about any error you do make is by definition untestable.

Use types that are much better suited to it. Peruse the `java.util.concurrent` package. For example, if you want one thread to be adding books and another to be removing them, you may want to look at [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Removing a 'random' book is rather complicated and doesn't seem pragmatically solvable unless you go with a lock-the-world model. That works too, you'd just have to festoon all interaction with `bookList` in a synchronized block. But that mostly defeats the point of threads, as only one thread would ever actually be running (the other is waiting to acquire the synchronized lock).

The takeaway lessons are:

- It is rocket science.
- Tests won't catch errors.
- Read the JMM if you really really want to do this. Learn about the ways to establish HB/HA and apply them. This requires knowing what `synchronized` and `volatile` actually do and is non-trivial to learn. If you misunderstood a few things but you don't realize you did, it is quite likely you'll never know until later when your code seems to randomly fail sometimes. This is not something a first-year java newbie should be tackling.
- Any concurrent access (interleaving reads/writes from different threads) on the same field are going to not work the way you want them to unless you pay extremely careful attention and set up HB/HA to make it reliable.
- Try to avoid concurrent access to fields, it's not that hard to do so:
- Peruse the j.u.concurrent package and use something from there, or
- arrange for communications between threads using a mechanism that's good at it, such as databases (which have transactions), or message queues such as RabbitMQ.